# Win32 program to search value from subkeys, Data and value in Dialog box on list control

Tags: winapi

I want a program in Win32 application in which when user enters a string in edit control, search is carried out through out registry to display string found at subkey or data or value.
Full path should be provided to user

Output should be displayed to user on grid control having 3 columns Subkey, Data and value

Some code done by me

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hwndButton[3], hwndEdit,hList;
    LPTSTR lpString=new TCHAR[1000];

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    wz_reg_path[i][0]=L'\0';
        wz_reg_value[i][0]=L'\0';
        wz_reg_data[i][0]=L'\0';

}

    hwndButton[1] = GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_CHECK1);
    hwndButton[2] = GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_CHECK2);
    hwndButton[3] = GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_CHECK3);
    hwndEdit=GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_EDIT1);
    hList=GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_LIST1);

    //UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON1)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK)
        {
            int stateCheck_check1,stateCheck_check2,stateCheck_check3, editcheck;

            stateCheck_check1=(int) SendMessage (hwndButton[1], BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0) ;
            stateCheck_check2=(int) SendMessage (hwndButton[2], BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0) ;
            stateCheck_check3=(int) SendMessage (hwndButton[3], BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0) ;

            editcheck=GetDlgItemText(hDlg,IDC_EDIT1,lpString,WM_GETTEXTLENGTH);

            if(editcheck >0 && stateCheck_check1==1 )
            {
                HKEY hKey[5];
                hKey[0]=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
                hKey[1]=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
                hKey[2]=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
                hKey[3]=HKEY_USERS;
                hKey[4]=HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG;

                HWND hList;
                hList=GetDlgItem (hDlg, IDC_LIST1);
                LVCOLUMN LvCol;
                LVITEM LvItem;
                memset(&LvCol,0,sizeof(LvCol));
                LvCol.mask=LVCF_TEXT|LVCF_WIDTH|LVCF_SUBITEM;
                LvCol.cx=0x28;
                LvCol.pszText=L"SubKey";
                LvCol.cx=0x98;
                SendMessage(hList,LVM_INSERTCOLUMN,0,(LPARAM)&LvCol); 

                LvCol.pszText=L"Values"; 
                SendMessage(hList,LVM_INSERTCOLUMN,1,(LPARAM)&LvCol); 

                LvCol.pszText=L"Data";     
                SendMessage(hList,LVM_INSERTCOLUMN,2,(LPARAM)&LvCol); 

                for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
                {
                    EnumerateSubKeys(hDlg,hKey[j],lpString);

                } 

                for(int i=0;i<icount_keys;i++)
                {
                memset(&LvItem,0,sizeof(LvItem)); 
                                LvItem.mask=LVIF_TEXT;
                                LvItem.cchTextMax = 256;
                                LvItem.iItem=1; 
                                LvItem.iSubItem=0;
                                LvItem.pszText= L"%ls", wz_reg_path; 

                                SendMessage(hList,LVM_INSERTITEM,0,(LPARAM)&LvItem);
                }

            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
DWORD data;

void EnumerateValues(HKEY hKey, DWORD numValues)
{
    DWORD valNameLen = 64;
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    LPTSTR valueName = new TCHAR[1000];
    DWORD dataType;

    DWORD dataSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
    {

        RegEnumValue(hKey,
            dwIndex,
            valueName,
            &valNameLen,
            NULL,
            &dataType,
            (BYTE*)&data,
            &dataSize);

        dwIndex++;

        wcscpy(wz_reg_value[0],valueName);

    }
}

void EnumerateSubKeys(HWND HDlg1 ,HKEY RootKey, LPTSTR subKey) 
{
    HKEY hKey;
    TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");   // buffer for class name 
    DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
    DWORD    cSubKeys=0;               // number of subkeys 
    DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
    DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
    DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
    DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
    DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
    DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

    HKEY hsubKey;
    DWORD  retCode; 


    retCode=RegOpenKeyEx(RootKey, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

    retCode=RegQueryInfoKey(RootKey,achClass,&cchClassName,NULL,&cSubKeys,
        &cbMaxSubKey,&cchMaxClass,&cValues,&cchMaxValue,&cbMaxValueData,
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,&ftLastWriteTime); 


    if(cSubKeys>0)
    {
        TCHAR currentSubkey[MAX_PATH];

        for(int i=0;i < cSubKeys;i++)
        {
            DWORD currentSubLen=MAX_PATH;

            retCode=RegEnumKeyEx(hKey,    // Handle to an open/predefined key
                i,                // Index of the subkey to retrieve.
                currentSubkey,            // buffer to receives the name of the subkey
                &currentSubLen,             // size of that buffer
                NULL,                // Reserved
                NULL,                // buffer for class string 
                NULL,                // size of that buffer
                &ftLastWriteTime);                // last write time

            if(StrStr(currentSubkey,subKey)!= NULL)
            {
                wcscpy(wz_reg_path[icount_keys],currentSubkey);
                icount_keys++;


                if(icount_keys==99)
                {
                    break;
                }




        retCode=RegOpenKeyEx(RootKey, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hsubKey);
        if(retCode==ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
                            EnumerateSubKeys(HDlg1,hsubKey, currentSubkey);
        }

            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        EnumerateValues(hKey, cValues);
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey); 
}
```

Comment: Post some code and show us where you are stuck.

Comment: done added code in question itself

Comment: So, what's the question? You haven't explained what the problem with your current code is.

Comment: actually when i am trying with above code, it is not displaying expected result. when i debugged the code, i found recursion is not working as expected

Comment: Please be more specific exactly how it is not "working as expected".

Comment: okay,actually first time loop iterates correctly, for example i enter ".ac" to search,  its first occurence is ".ac3" in "HKEY_Root" , it will store ".ac3" in my string array, then it should move forward and iterate next subkey  either in "HKEY_Root" and so on. but it again iterates with same subkey that is".ac3"